# export keyword in BASH scripting

Tags: bash, export, keyword

I am trying to install PETSc on my Ubuntu laptop. The first step of the installation is to invoke the following commands in the top level directory of the PETSc directory in the terminal.

```
export PETSC_DIR=$PWD
./config/configure.py --with-cc=gcc --with-fc=gfortran --download-f-blas-lapack=1 --download-mpich=1
make all test
```

Question 1:  Should I actually enter in the word  'PWD' or the address of the top level PETSc directory?

Question 2:
What I wanted to understand what the export keyword does in general and in particular what it does in the example. I have looked at some references on the export keyword and all of them did not really explain clearly. Probably I have been looking in the wrong places.

I have never done any shell scripting so a detailed answer would be very helpful...Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 7):

All `export` does is make the value of an environment variable available to child processes.

In this case, they're assuming that you're in the top level directory of the PETSc directory.  So using $PWD (print working directory) is just a shortcut so you don't have to type out the path.  The effect should be identical:

```
[jm72@localhost PETSc_1_1_1_1]$ pwd
/home/jm72/soft/PETSc_1_1_1_1
[jm72@localhost PETSc_1_1_1_1]$ export PETSC_DIR=$PWD
[jm72@localhost PETSc_1_1_1_1]$ echo $PETSC_DIR
/home/jm72/soft/PETSc_1_1_1_1
[jm72@localhost PETSc_1_1_1_1]$ export PETSC_DIR=/home/jm72/soft/PETSC_1_1_1_1
[jm72@localhost PETSc_1_1_1_1]$ echo $PETSC_DIR
/home/jm72/soft/PETSC_1_1_1_1
```

Comment: `export` doesn't set an environment variable, it marks it for exporting into child processes.  `FOO=BAR` sets variable `$FOO` but does not export it to child processes, and `export FOO` marks `$FOO` for export without altering the value of it.  `export FOO=BAR` is an alias for `FOO=BAR; export FOO`.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  It was clear the OP was coming from the position of a beginner so I didn't want to make the explanation too complicated, but I've edited my answer to better reflect reality.

Comment: Ahhh thank you Adam and Jacob!  That helped a lot! But I don't get what Adam says about child processes. What is a process? Is it one single session between opening and closing my gnome-terminal?

Comment: Also once we export a variable in one gnome-terminal session, then close the terminal and open it again, can we use the same environmental variables we defined in the previous session?

Comment: No, a process is a container that holds a running task.  Each time you start an application or execute a command, it runs inside a process, which contains a set of environment variables.  The set of variables that is made available to the process is influenced by export.  For example, if I have two terminal windows open, and I export a new variable at the command line of one window, and then run an application from the command line of the other window, it won't know about the new variable (because it isn't a child process of the environment into which I exported the variable).

Comment: If you need your environment variables to be accessible across different sessions as you describe, you need to add them to an initialization script such as .bash_profile.

Comment: ahh...that clears it....one more question. So a child process is a process which is called by another process right? Meaning two processes which have nothing to do with each other (e.g. ls and cd Desktop, say) but were started in the same terminal need not be have a child/parent relationship????

Comment: Correct.  The terminal itself is running in a process, so processes that are started from the terminal are child processes of the terminal process.  If you like, you can think of them as sibling processes.

Comment: Try using the command `pstree`; it shows a list of running processes and their parent-child relationships.